# Vagrant error: "The site you have requested is not installed"

Tags: wordpress, vagrant

When running my usual *vagrant up*, it now returns an error "The site you have requested is not installed."  And indeed, when I try to access my usual local WordPress installation, instead of loading my half-completed website, it prompts me to begin a new WordPress installation.  How can I get Vagrant to point back to my existing WordPress site?

All my previous WordPress files (specifically, those in the wp-content folder) for my site still exist on my local computer, in the same directory.

[Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/h3ssu7yq) to the full *vagrant up* output.

***vagrant up* errors:**

```
==> default: Updating WordPress Stable...
==> default: Error: The site you have requested is not installed.
==> default: Run `wp core install`.
```

---

```
==> default: From https://github.com/creationix/nvm
==> default:  * branch            master     -> FETCH_HEAD
==> default: error: Your local changes to the following files would be overwritten by merge:
```

---

```
==> default: error: The following untracked working tree files would be overwritten by checkout:
```

---

```
==> default: Installing/updating wp-cli and debugging tools
==> default: Updating wp-cli...
==> default: error: Cannot pull with rebase: You have unstaged changes.
```

edit:  Perhaps I should note that I am using VVV.

Answer (score 1):

OK I resolved my issue by doing the following:

- Navigating to the URL of my local WordPress install, and walking through the new WordPress installation, per the on-screen prompts.
- Upon doing so, I saw that all of my themes/plugins (i.e. wp-content files) were still present within WordPress.
- I then used my usual database migration plugin (Migrate DB) to migrate my online database to my local database (since my online WordPress site is identical to my local WordPress site).  I *tried* exporting my online database, then importing it to my local site using phpmyadmin, but that caused weird login issues.

I'm still not sure exactly why this occurred.  I know that it all began after I shut down Windows after forgetting to run a *vagrant suspend*.  Then I carried out several poorly documented troubleshooting steps of my own, which exacerbated the situation.